# Using Eclipse, trying to get a program to work

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently learning Java with eclipse for my computer science course, and I need some assistance trying to figure out how to fix the error that is currently showing.

```js
package sec4Les2;

public class RoseDS4L2Person {
 //creating the variables
 public String name = "Uma Thurman";
 public int Age = 0;
 
 //constructor
 
 public RoseDS4L2Person()
 {
  
 }
 
 public String getname()
 {
  //will return first name
  return name;
 }
 public int getAge()
 {
  //will return age
  return Age;
 }
public void setAge(int Age)
 {
 //will set age to int
 this.Age = Age;
 }
}
```

And here is the running code:

```js
package sec4Les2;

public class RoseDS4L2ManagingPeople {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  //runs information in first class file
  
  RoseDS4L2Person p1 = new RoseDS4L2Person("Arial", 37);
  RoseDS4L2Person p2 = new RoseDS4L2Person ("Joseph", 15);
  
  if(p1.getAge()==p2.getAge())
  {
   System.out.println(p1.getname()+" is the same age as "+p2.getname());
  }
  else
  {
   System.out.println(p1.getname()+" is NOT the same age as "+p2.getname());
  }
 }
}
```

It says there are no errors on the first one, but the second one has errors on the p1/p2 lines. How can I fix this error? thank you!

Comment: Add a constructor for RoseDS4L2ManagingPeople class that takes a String and an Integer

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code to your class. Basically, a constructor was missing in your class. Also note that by convention, member variables start in lowercase. So your `Age` should really be `age`.

Another thing is, you  have kept name as constant. Probably you want to remove "Uma Thurman". If you want to keep that as default name for all objects where name is not specified at initialization time, you would want to add that in the constructor. *

```
public class RoseDS4L2Person 
    {
        // other lines ....
        RoseDS4L2Person(String name, int age) {
          this.Age = age;
          this.name = name;
         }

       }
```

*

Something like this:

```
public class RoseDS4L2Person 
        {

private static final String UMA_THURMAN = "Uma Thurman";
            // other lines ....

 RoseDS4L2Person( int age) {
              this.Age = age;
              this.name = UMA_THURMAN;
             }
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice, code only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a constructor for RoseDS4L2Person accepting a string and a number, like so:

```
public RoseDS4L2Person(String name, int age)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.Age = age;
}
```

This will allow you to create an instance of the class passing a name and an age as parameters.

Answer (score -1):

The error is popping up because you have created objects with a non-existing constructor.Making objects with the default constructor or creating a constructor 
which can accept the arguments you pass should do the trick.
Happy Coding